# Can you run the B programming language on Linux (more specifically Raspbian)?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, b-lang

Recently I've been reading Brian Kernighan's book on B (https://web.archive.org/web/20150611114427/https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.pdf) and I was wondering if I could actually run B scripts on Linux. Are there any compilers out there? I'm just really interested in seeing how C was programmed. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone have a working B compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601243/does-anyone-have-a-working-b-compiler)

Comment: Thanks! All my search results came up with "How to run C on Linux"